# Issue with Phabricator configuration for MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, phabricator

I am able to get to the URL for phabricator.  When I run the following the script from the phabricator directory, I receive the error copied below.  I have also copied the mysql config info from the custom/myconfig.conf.php file (the credentials work - I can log on via the terminal using mysql -u root -p).  I will change the credentials to non root once I can test the setup.

**myconfig.conf.php**

```
  // DatabaseConfigurationProvider.
  'mysql.configuration-provider' => 'DefaultDatabaseConfigurationProvider',

  // The username to use when connecting to MySQL.
  'mysql.user' => 'root',

  // The password to use when connecting to MySQL.
  'mysql.pass' => 'xxxxxxxxx',

  // The MySQL server to connect to.
  'mysql.host' => '127.0.0.1', ///'localhost',

  // If you want to connect to a different port than the default (which is 3306)
  'mysql.port' => null,
```

**Error after running ./bin/storage upgrade**

```
Unable To Connect: Attempt to connect to root@localhost failed with error #1045: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO).
```

MySQL is listening on 127.0.0.1:3306.  I have tried the following as well (passing in root ID as well) but it did not work:
./bin/storage upgrade --user  --password

**Update:**
When I run the ./bin/storage upgrade command with a new set of credentials, I get the following error:

```
        [2014-05-07 16:15:16] EXCEPTION: (RuntimeException) Undefined property:

     DefaultDatabaseConfigurationProvider::$getPassword at

     [/usr/local/phabricator/libphutil/src/error/PhutilErrorHandler.php:216]

          #0 PhutilErrorHandler::handleError(8, Undefined property: 

    DefaultDatabaseConfigurationProvider::$getPassword,


     /usr/local/phabricator/phabricator/scripts/sql/manage_storage.php, 75, 

Array of size 16 starting with: { _GET => Array  }) called at 

    [/usr/local/phabricator/phabricator/scripts/sql/manage_storage.php:75]
```

The storage now works with a new DB credentials if I pass in the username/password in the storage upgrade command but its not picked up correctly from the conf file.  I will check the conf and update this accordingly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The storage now works with a new DB credentials if I pass in the username/password in the storage upgrade command but its not picked up correctly from the conf file. I will check the conf and update this accordingly.

```
./bin/storage upgrade --user "actual username" --password "actual password"
```

Answer (score 5):

hi i solved the issue very easily after spent 2 days :

```
./bin/config set mysql.host 'localhost'

./bin/config set mysql.user 'root'

./bin/config set mysql.pass 'pass'
```

don't forget the quotes !!!

Answer (score 1):

In some situations this is not enough: ./bin/storage upgrade wants to create new database, but phabricatos user does not have privileges to create databases.
So i suggest to grant all privileges phabricator user all phabricator_* for databases (existing and created in future) using this mysql code `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON`phabricator_%`.* TO 'phabricator'@'localhost';`

Answer (score 0):

> late answer, hope it helps new comers

phabricator provides mechanism to configure the username and password for mysql connection

```
  phabricator/ $ ./bin/config set mysql.host __host__
  phabricator/ $ ./bin/config set mysql.user __username__
  phabricator/ $ ./bin/config set mysql.pass __password__
```

also alternatively you can update the config file at

`phabricator/ $ ./conf/local/local.json`

```
{
  "mysql.user": "phabricator_user_in_mysql"
}
```

make sure this user has proper access grants in mysql

then run 
`./bin/storage upgrade`